# Unexpected results when subtracting two rasters from each other in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm using ArcMap version 10.5 , I have to subtract one raster from another.
The first raster has  "unique values" clusters:

[image]

when each cluster here has numeric value.

The second raster has more variance in their values and sit on top of the first raster:

[image]

I'm using raster calculator to subtract the second from the first and I expect to get new raster that will be influenced from raster two :

```
"%ras1%"-"%ras2%"
```

However, the results look like this:

[image]

and it seems like the  the subtraction is not working as each "cluster" has only one value for all the pixels inside it. though I subtracted different values from each pixel.

I don't know why is this happening.

**My end goal : to get correct result of the subtraction.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcMap's raster calculator has a habit of making the result Integer. Check if this is your problem and, if so, to resolve this, you must wrap one of your input rasters into the `Float()` function